# How to specify the memory size in ubuntu in GB?

Tags: ram

I am trying to know what is the memory size in GB in a Ubuntu server. What do these values mean?

```
>> free -to
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:    1058740404   57548396 1001192008          0     740412   39295428
Swap:      8388600     690948    7697652
Total:  1067129004   58239344 1008889660
```

I tried to convert 1058740404 from kB to GB but the result was unrealistic (1058.47 GB).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using free

To show In GB run the command:

```
free -g
```

---

#### Using dmidecode

Run the command:

```
sudo dmidecode -t 17
```

It will show you full description of every  memory slot.

---

#### Now What did that values from free mean?

First, note this:

1. Linux uses perm storage device (⁖ hard-disk ) as virtual memory. The
   virtual memory on hard-disk is called swap space. Virtual memory
   means the perm storage is used as temp space for RAM. So, when your
   RAM is full, the OS can off-load parts of it currently not used data
   to disk, therefore free up memory for application that needs it.
2. Also, Linux uses RAM as cache for file data (from hard-disk).
   (Because RAM's IO speed is a thousand times faster than hard disk,
   so OS will load disk data to RAM as cache)

example: output of free -m (“-m” means mega bytes).

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          5798       2145       3653          0        160       1121
-/+ buffers/cache:        862       4935
Swap:         5885          0       5885
```

in the first row Mem, the total 5798 is the total RAM.

used + free = total. Check: 2145 + 3653 = 5798.

“used” includes used for disk cache purposes.

“cached” is amount of disk data sitting in RAM for fast access.

So, real free should be “free + buffers + cached”, and in this example it is 3653 + 160 + 1121 = 4934.

and actually used should be “used - buffers - cached” (2145 - 160 - 1121 = 864).

And if we add 4934 and 864 we get the “total”.

Explanation of free is quoted from http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_free_memory.html

Comment: There's also free -h, which is best for redability.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 There is no `-h` option for `free`, check `man free`.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 maybe you mix between free and some other tools such as `du` and `df` ..

Comment: I apologize. I myself do `free -m`. Slipped my mind.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 don't be, it's normal.. thanks for your help

Comment: There is indeed an `-h` option for `free`. http://paste.ubuntu.com/11903047/